# Memory leak with AfxBeginThread

Tags: c++, mfc

Updated. I've been struggling with this all day, butchered my code and finally decided to go back and try something a bit different.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding but...

Both Windows Resource Monitor and Memory Validator (a 3rd party tool) indicate that the `AfxBeginThread` is consuming memory. If I call the same class without creating a thread, the memory stays constant. Because this is called on a cycle it is, over time, becoming a liability.

I thought maybe it was something dumb in my class so I created a new class, with nothing in it except the call to `IsBusy()` and have it launch in a thread. It still consumes memory.

The odd thing is that neither VS debugger or the Memory Validator tool see any memory loss. But Windows Resource Monitor is quite clear that memory usage is going up.

Question: When does the thread actually release memory? Is it at the end of `RunImports()`. Or does this thread actually persist for the life of the class `TillBotTimer`? Maybe that's the problem is my assumption in how this all cleans up if it is called repeatedly?

```
UINT LaunchImportThread(LPVOID lParam)
{
    int iReturn=1;

    TillBotImport *pTBI = (TillBotImport *)lParam;

    return(iReturn);
}

void TillBotTimer::RunImports()
{
    CTestThread piPoll;

    AfxBeginThread(LaunchImportThread, &piPoll);

    while (piPoll.IsBusy()) {
        Sleep(0);
        ProcessMessages();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no leak in the code posted. All MFC exceptions are properly `Delete()`d in the `END_CATCH` macro, and the only `new`ed object is `delete`d, too. Either there is a leak in the code we cannot see (post a [mcve], please), or the leak detection tool gets confused.

Comment: Thanks. One of my challenges figuring out the minimum reproducible example. That  object that is being allocated has a lot going on. So I've got a needle in the haystack kind of thing going on to figure out how to find it.

I guess I'm wondering if that class, being handled by the thread, gets cleaned up differently than one that isn't in a thread? I think I may only be able to answer this by going an ripping it apart.

Comment: Here's something else: if I comment out pTBI->RunImport (and make sure the flag Busy is set to false so it falls through) the memory leak stops. If I go in to the actual code for RunImport() and comment out the entire body of the code, so it does nothing, the memory leak happens. So how can it make a difference if it is or is not executing the function that has no code in it?

Comment: Object cleanup doesn't get handled differently, when you are passing a non-owning pointer into a thread. It's just a value, and neither the OS nor the runtime attributes any particular meaning to it. It's no different from passing a boolean `false` or the integer `42`. But now that you have a [mcve] you might want to update your question.

Comment: Thanks. Updated with what has become pretty limited code. :)

Comment: Well, I apologize for being so thick but that's the answer -- I was creating that thread over and over again and it was never cleaning up or being deleted. Create it once and because it has to do a couple different things iteratively, set a state. But I made a very wrong assumption that it would go away somehow. Thanks for helping! Sometimes it helps to have someone just to bounce it around with.